# How to download files in android?

Tags: android, httpclient

I am using `URLConnection` to download files onto my SD card. This works fine, but I think that `HTTPClient` would be a better way. So How do I do that?

```
 URL url = new URL( aurl[0] );
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();
            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            Log.d( "ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile );
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream( url.openStream() );
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream( ApkFileDirectory );
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            while ((count = input.read( data )) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress( "" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile) );
                output.write( data, 0, count );
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
```

Comment: what makes you think you should use `HTTPClient` instead? Which API level are you targeting?

Comment: I've used both `HttpURLConnection` and `HTTPClient`. For apps targeting older os versions it is probably worth the effort to import the Apache library. But `HttpURLConnection` has improved and I have experienced no issues with it. What are your concerns?

Comment: I would say `HTTPClient` is depreciated. `HttpURLConnection` is pretty much up-to-date.